# What is the difference between iCalendar and CalDav?

Tags: icalendar, caldav

What is the difference between iCalendar and CalDav?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30053513/5389585) for the user's perspective on subscribing to an iCal over HTTP vs. CalDav.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

CalDAV is a protocol extension for WebDAV and can used to manipulate data in the iCalendar format. So CalDAV is like the HTTP for calendar stuff, and iCalendar is like HTML.

Comment: People on the internet use the terms icalendar and CalDAV interchangeably. 
"so caldav is like the http for calender stuff, and ical is like html".
I think this explains it best.

Comment: I think this is a good analogue, though some calendars may expose a calendar both through the caldav protocol and some icalendar link.  In that case the answer below from Bobik is correct.

Answer (score 29):

[iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) is a file format that can be used to store and transport calendar entries.

[CalDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CalDAV) is a protocol specification, based on HTTP/WebDAV, that can be used to interact with remote calendars.

CalDAV uses the iCalendar format to represent the actual entries.

Answer (score 25):

In case a calendar is exposed either through a caldav link or an icalendar link, the difference is:

### iCal

- Read-only
- Just one file with all events, so client have to download whole feed (so syncing is not data effective)

### CalDAV

- Read-write
- Like multiple files, so client can download only some events (support effective syncing)
- Access control list
- Read-free-busy (see only time, not details about event)

Comment: I initially downvoted this one because I think it's incorrect (ref the accepted answer), but thinking twice - you are completely right for the case when a calendar is exposed both with a caldav link and an icalendar link.  I'll take the liberty to edit this answer a bit.