# Does CalDAV on Google support adding/removing on event-by-event base?

Tags: google-calendar-api, caldav

We are writing Web-based software which should allow to automatically schedule events via Google Calendar.

Should we use Google Calendar API or is it OK to use CalDAV?

Do I understand correctly that CalDAV of Google calendar allows to upload only the complete iCalendar file rather than separate events? This I would consider unacceptable for us.

If I cannot edit on event-by-event basis easily enough, I would use Google Calendar API rather than CalDAV. But I am not sure if this is possible with CalDAV. Please help.

Comment: Have you seen the [Specifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/caldav/v2/guide) of CALDav API? It lists there what it can and cannot do. It's looks very limited if you ask me.

Comment: I suppose it would be best if you use Google API. Back then, Google attempted to deprecate support for CalDav. Only because there were many requests to keep it, then Google changed their mind. https://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html

Answer (score 0):

> Should we use Google Calendar API or is it OK to use CalDAV?

It is certainly preferable to use CalDAV, as it is an open and standard protocol supported by many. E.g. you may also want to supported iCloud in the future ...

> Do I understand correctly that CalDAV of Google calendar allows to upload only the complete iCalendar file rather than separate events?

No. CalDAV allows you to upload separate events. You are talking about WebCal, this question is related: [What's the difference between Webcal and WebDAV/CalDAV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30048720/whats-the-difference-between-webcal-and-webdav-caldav)

> If I cannot edit on event-by-event basis easily enough, I would use Google Calendar API rather than CalDAV. But I am not sure if this is possible with CalDAV.

It is possible. You just PUT the updated event to the event URL.

This is a great introduction on how to build a CalDAV client:
[Building a CalDAV client](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/).